# Meteor: About Password Encryption

Tags: django, encryption, meteor

I'm thinking about migrating one of my django application to meteor. But there is one question I'm trying to answer before doing this: How does Meteor encrypt a password? (with the account-password package?)

In my case, I used the default django password encryption:

```
Django provides a flexible password storage system and uses PBKDF2 by default.
The password attribute of a User object is a string in this format:

<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>
```

So my passwords are stored like this:

pbkdf2_sha256$12000$Z0rof3EQy1p2$wezcf334ytyBm12CPcdlNZLrkWYkaQklk4wHt5jxgWE=

Is it impossible to make Meteor adopt the same scheme so as my current users can continue to use my application without resetting their password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`accounts-password` uses [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol) to authenticate users. This was mentioned in the [blog post](https://www.meteor.com/blog/2012/10/17/meteor-050-authentication-user-accounts-new-screencast) for meteor 0.5:

> Support for the Secure Remote Password protocol. Developed at Stanford, SRP lets a user securely log in to a server without ever sending that server their unencrypted password. The kind of high-profile security breaches at LinkedIn and Pandora earlier this year are impossible with SRP. Instead of asking every application developer to safely store passwords, we've baked the very best technology right into Meteor Accounts.

It's also discussed a little bit in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tObIpzqW4Aw) recent video. Side note - it's interesting that they are considering adding bcrypt in the future.

So for now, the good news is that meteor does not store password-equivalent information in the database. The bad news is that your users will need to reset their passwords if you choose to migrate your framework.

Comment: Regarding the actual conversion of passwords to SRP, it seems the OP has some time so I'd suggest prepending a step into the normal Django login flow which takes the plaintext password and stores the SRP equivalent when the user logs in.  Over time the SRP set will grow to match your active userbase and conversion won't be as painful.  Inactive users can be prompted to reset their password when needed.